# Does the Dashlane windows application actually override the PATH variable?

Tags: windows, passwords, password-management, dashlane

Am I overlooking something or do they really just overwrite your PATH environment variable with `%DASHLANE_DLL_DIR%`?

Comment: It would help with adding how your environment variables look like...

Comment: They look very much like `PATH = %DASHLANE_DLL_DIR%` and `%DASHLANE_DLL_DIR% = {some_dashlane_dir}`. I'm just in disbelief that an otherwise well-working software just destroys your path variable, and was hoping someone using it could validate this for me before I spread false blame.

Comment: I tried installing it, and it just appends the %DASHLANE_DLL_DIR% to the end of my user environment variable path

Comment: Also, when uninstalling it, it doesn't clean up the env variables :-/

Comment: I see, thanks. Must have been something else that removed my other PATH entries then.

Comment: I just discovered dashlane has destroyed my Path variable in user variables section.